# How to specify arbitrarily the thickness of lines or size of points in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I know there are options such as `PointSize[Large]` or `PlotStyle -> Thick`, but what if I want to even larger or thicker? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PointSize[number]` -- size relative to the image

`AbsolutePointSize[number]` -- absolute size in points

`Thickness[number]` -- thickness relative to the image

`AbsoluteThickness[number]` -- absolute thickness in points

Basically the size given by `PointSize[0.1]` and `Thickness[0.1]` scale as you resize the graphic. `AbsolutePointSize[10]` and `AbsoluteThickness[10]` are always the same size, regardless of the size of the graphic.

Comment: @Daniel: Regarding to Daniel's comment. This is what I like to know too. More examples of this sort: obtain the origin information, obtain the plot range information etc. Do anybody know how to get this sort of information?

Answer (score 0):

*(sorry, new user here - is it appropriate to ask a closely related "follow up" question in this manner?  If not please advise and I will delete...)*

EDIT: moved to [a standalone question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174250/can-relative-size-changes-be-made-to-pointsize-thickness-in-mathematica)

EDIT: @Qiang re: *obtain the origin information, obtain the plot range information etc.* you'll find a lot of what you want from `AbsoluteOptions[]`

Comment: I think that's enough different to warrant a separate thread.