# Can relative size changes be made to PointSize[], Thickness[] in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Arising from [this question regarding line thickness and point size setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162886) [e.g. `PointSize[Large}`, `PointSize[0.5]`), I was wondering if it is feasible to change `PointSize[]`, `Thickness[]` etc in a *relative* manner?

I.e. why is it that `PointSize[Larger]` doesn't work?  Or is possible to somehow query the existing pointsize and perhaps do something like`PointSize[1.25*GetPointSize[]]` (I haven't been able to figure this out if something like "GetPointSize[]" exists, neither with a quick look at the documentation, nor from a quick reverse-engineering look at PointSize[x])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using the Style option form of PointSize with Inherited in the value:

```
Graphics[{Style[{Point[{0, 0}], 
Style[{Point[{.2, 0}], 
  Style[{Point[{.4, 0}], 
    Style[{Point[{.6, 0}], 
      Style[{Point[{.8, 0}]}, PointSize -> .9 Inherited]}, 
     PointSize -> .9 Inherited]}, PointSize -> .9 Inherited]}, 
 PointSize -> .9 Inherited]}, PointSize -> .1]}, PlotRange -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? In my manual PointSize is a `Directive`, not an `Option`. All the PointSize occurrences in your snippet are shown as syntax errs in **my** Mma

Comment: @belisarius thanks for the `Directive`/`Option` distinction.  What I am really at a loss to figure out though is why it actually works (!), even though the frontend thinks it's an error, and also the documentation for `Inherited` seems pretty clear that it deals with `Option`s.

Comment: I had been hoping to find something that worked "as you went along the list" rather than "as you got deeper into a nested structure".  But, thanks for adding another little tool to my box.

Answer (score 4):

Those options that Mathematica keeps track of are revealed by `AbsoluteOptions[]`
Try  `AbsoluteOptions[Graphics[{Point[{0, 0}]}]]`, for example.
Unfortunately, PointSize is not among the options tracked.

So, why not simply use a variable to store the value to use?

```
ps = 0.01; Graphics[{PointSize[ps], 
  Table[Point[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}], {i, 100}]}]
```

[image]

Then...

```
Graphics[{PointSize[ps*2], 
  Table[Point[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}], {i, 100}]}]
```

[image: I'd post an image but I don't have 10 points yet!]

Comment: Well, now you can post images :)

Comment: thanks, I knew about `AbsoluteOptions` (and was pretty impressed with that idea when I discovered it!), I couldn't figure out why `PointSize` wouldn't be an `Option`.

Comment: Thanks, Belisarius.  I just added my first pictures.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment to Belisarius'  "Directive" comments due to lack of points, so I chime in here:

Ragfield's code works, but all `PointSize` instructions are indeed marked red. Formatted as directives it still works and isn't marked as erroneous too:

```
Graphics[
 {
 Style[
  {
   Point[{0, 0}],
   Style[
    {
     Point[{.2, 0}],
     Style[
      {
       Point[{.4, 0}],
       Style[
        {
         Point[{.6, 0}],
         Style[
          {
           Point[{.8, 0}]
          },
          PointSize[.9 Inherited]
         ]
        },
        PointSize[.9 Inherited]
       ]
      },
      PointSize[.9 Inherited]
     ]
    },
    PointSize[.9 Inherited]
   ]
  },
  PointSize[.1]
 ]
},
PlotRange -> 1
]
```

I like a bit of formatting for deeply nested structures like this. Anyone know how you can paste formatted Mma code in Stackoverflow without having to do manual formatting afterwards?

Nice to hear about `Inherited` BTW. Apparently new since v6, but it flew under my radar.

Comment: Odd that the frontend doesn't flag it here as an argument to `PointSize` but does over there (I suppose it's easier for it to recognize that `PointSize` is not an option; still it doesn't seem that much of a bigger step for it to know where `Inherited` will produce meaningful results and where it won't).  Even odder of course is that `Inherited` works (!!); no complaints about this though...